# Has anyone ever had to "rebalance" their Python file-seeker? Bug?

Tags: python, file-io

In a very nasty script I finally got working, I actually had to rebalance the seeker thusly

```
f.seek(0, 1)
```

before the f.write() function would write anything that "stuck". I mean I tried so many ways to get around this, but the only thing that worked was the above simple line.

Naturally i checked the pointer with f.tell() before and after the write - identical!

I am using Python 2.7.3 for this script. Might this be a bug? I feel weary of using this as it seems... well.. too weird.

Comment: Weird indeed. Can you produce an SSCCE? http://sscce.org/

Comment: Did you read from the file before attempting to write? A seek may be required between reading and writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does sound weird. The only explanation that comes to mind is that you are not taking the effects of buffering into account.

Specifically, when you write something to a file, it is written to an internal buffer first. The contents of the buffer is written to the file when

- the buffer is full; or
- the file is closed; or
- `f.flush()` is called; or
- `f.seek()` is called.

Thus, if you were to examine the contents of the file after writing a bit of data to it *but before any of the above happens*, you would often not see the newly-written data.

Comment: I will try to use that fact in some way. But it is indeed againt us for the following reasons: (1) the write is not yet done, (2) the file was never closed, (3) other operations (seeks and writes) were made afterwards which should have made the buffer empty properly into the write-spots.. just weird. anyway, I guess it's answered! I may revive this if the same is not true in Python 3.x but for now I need some old libs so it's all in 2.7.3.